# Compilation error - package com.google.gson not found in Redhat "Openshift" application

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gson, openshift

I am devleoping application in openshift using Eclipse Luna which make use of gson jars.

I added gson jar files in the Web-inf/lib folder and it is not showing any error in eclipse.

But when I **Push and Commit** the application to the GIT repository, it is showing error:

I also tried adding jars in the external libraries
Configure Build path -> Add external jars....

But still not working !!

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/openshift/54d3ce57fcf933ba9b00000a/app-
root/runtime/repo/src/main/java/com/servlet/Controller_vehicle.java:[14,22]
 error: package com.google.gson does not exist
```

Is openshift not supporting gson packages ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK ! i got it.
For any external jars that you add in the libraries in java openshift application, you have to show the dependency in the **pom.xml** file
This file is in webapps folder i.e. webapps/pom.xml.

I used gson-2.1.jar, so the corresponding dependency is :-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to me :)

Comment: Your answer in only specified for a Maven Project, It wont solve on a gradle project though